# Changing last 2 characters font size with php and regex

Tags: php, regex

I have a menu that I am loading onto a template. The only issue is the the way they want it to look is to have the first number normal font size (lets say 12px) and the last numbers to be smaller (lets say 9px)

Is there a way to automatically find the last 2 characters and change the font size? Because the menu varies. It could be 7.99 or it could be 12.99. I could easily make the call saying the 3rd and fourth character will change but it's so variable. Thanks for any help in the right direction.

```
$spaces = str_replace(" ", "", $this->orderData->menu1);
$checkPrice =preg_replace('/^(\d{3})(\d{3})$/', '$1.$2', $spaces);
```

Comment: show your code and data

Answer (score 0):

Yes,
I'm, assuming that 12.99 is a price and you want .99 to be smaller.
I will inject an inline style for this example but it could be a class name also...

```
// Lets assume the string is this
$string = "Hello, the price of pie is 12.99 today but now the pie is only 1.99 and not .99p";

// Let's replace the pence with any number between 1.00 and 9999.99
$string = preg_replace("/([0-9]{1,4})\.([0-9]{2})/is","\$1.<span style='font-size:9px'>\$2</span>",$string);

// If you wanted the price of ".99" too (meaning there are no pounds)
// then this would work
$string = preg_replace("/([0-9]{0,4})\.([0-9]{2})/is","\$1.<span style='font-size:9px'>\$2</span>",$string);
```

Comment: Instead of hard coding a font, give it a class so that the size is controlled via your stylesheet.

Comment: Yes good point, I did already mention that at the start and it's completely down to them what they want to stick as the HTML result, the important part is how they replace the 99 with something else!